# sed: set multiple lines below with same beginning

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file as follows

```
# jkakjshkjh
  *   drink  (2 spaces *  2 spaces)(non hash starting)
 *   biscuit  (1 space * 2 spaces)(non hash starting)
* paper       (* 1 space)(non has starting)
... (many more lines) of non hash starting
     *  tea   (7 spaces * 3 space)(non has starting)
# happy
* cup       (* 1 space)(non has starting)
  *   bat  (2 spaces *  2 spaces)(non hash starting)
 *   scooter  (1 space * 2 spaces)(non hash starting)
... (many more lines) of non hash starting
     *  disk   (7 spaces * 3 space)(non has starting)
```

I want all the non hash starting line to have the same beginning as the first non hash starting line

i.e:

```
# jkakjshkjh
  *   drink  (2 spaces *  2 spaces)(non hash starting)
  *   biscuit  (2 spaces *  2 spaces)(non hash starting)
  *   paper  (2 spaces *  2 spaces)(non hash starting)
   ... (many more lines of non hash starting)
  *   tea  (2 spaces *  2 spaces)(non hash starting)
# happy
* cup       (* 1 space)(non has starting)
* bat       (* 1 space)(non has starting)
* scooter       (* 1 space)(non has starting)
... (many more lines) of non hash starting
* disk       (* 1 space)(non has starting)
```

Now there is a twist in the above problem.

1) The first non hash line is not always starting with (2 spaces *  2 spaces)

It can vary (1 space * 1 space) or (radon number of pre spaces * random number of post spaces)

2) Inbetween if there is a line starting with hash it should not touch that line

So how to solve the above with sed

I have tried the below:

```
sed -Ez 's/(\n)([^#]\s+\*\s+)([^\n]*\n)([^#]\s+\*\s+)([^\n]*\n)/\1\2\3\2\5/g' filename
```

the above will only check for two consequite lines. Problem with this is it treats 2 lines as one unit. So groups of two lines will have same beginning. But i want all of them to have the same beginning as the first non hash starting line

Comment: i have mentioned what i have tried

Comment: I don't understand your `n space * m space` notation. Is `n` pre-\*-space and `m` post-*-space - 1?

Comment: Do you have to do this in sed?

Comment: Does every `non hash starting line` start with `<blanks>*`? Are all leading spaces blanks or could they be tabs too?

Comment: Yes all the non hash starting lines  start with <blanks>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're OK with a non-sed solution: with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    match($0,/^(\s*(\S)\s*)(.*)/,a)
    currHead = a[1]
    currChar = a[2]
    currTail = a[3]
}
currChar == "#" { indent = currHead }
currChar != "#" { indent = (prevChar == "#" ? currHead : indent) }
{ printf "%s%s\n", indent, currTail; prevChar = currChar }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
# jkakjshkjh
  *   drink  (2 spaces *  2 spaces)(non hash starting)
  *   biscuit  (1 space * 2 spaces)(non hash starting)
  *   paper       (* 1 space)(non has starting)
  *   .. (many more lines) of non hash starting
  *   tea   (7 spaces * 3 space)(non has starting)
# happy
* cup       (* 1 space)(non has starting)
* bat  (2 spaces *  2 spaces)(non hash starting)
* scooter  (1 space * 2 spaces)(non hash starting)
* .. (many more lines) of non hash starting
* disk   (7 spaces * 3 space)(non has starting)
```

With other awks you'd just use `substr()`s to get the parts that `match()` is putting in `a[]` for gawk and use `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]` for `\s` and `\S` respectively.

To help you understand the syntax, if I were writing the above in a C-like language then it'd be:

```
while ( read(FILENAME,line) ) {                 # awk does this for you
    NR++;                                       # awk does this for you
    NF = split(line into $1, $2, $3, ... $NF);  # awk does this for you
    match(line,/^(\s*(\S)\s*)(.*)/,a);
    currHead = a[1];
    currChar = a[2];
    currTail = a[3];
    if (currChar == "#") { indent = currHead; }
    if (currChar != "#") { indent = (prevChar == "#" ? currHead : indent); }
    printf "%s%s\n", indent, currTail; prevChar = currChar;
}                                               # awk does this for you
```

and in fact you can duplicate that syntax in awks BEGIN section with:

```
BEGIN {
    filename = ARGV[1]
    ARGV[1] = ""
    ARGC--
    while ( (getline line < filename) > 0) ) {
        nr++
        nf = split(line,flds)
        match(line,/^(\s*(\S)\s*)(.*)/,a)
        currHead = a[1]
        currChar = a[2]
        currTail = a[3]
        if (currChar == "#") { indent = currHead }
        if (currChar != "#") { indent = (prevChar == "#" ? currHead : indent) }
        printf "%s%s\n", indent, currTail; prevChar = currChar
    }
}
```

but see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for why not to do that unless you have a very specific need.

Comment: I will definitely check this.

Comment: I wanted to ask should i know both awk and sed . Is awk more recommended for programmers

Comment: OK let me know if any parts of it aren't clear. btw [@oguzismail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680513/1745001) should work just fine too given your non-# lines are all * lines and it's briefer and portable to all awks.

Comment: `prevChar = currChar` . Will this be stored when awk moves to the next line

Comment: No, it's stored when awk is reading the current line and then used in `prevChar == "#"` when awk moves to the next line. Imagine the whole script is wrapped in a `while read $0 { split($0 into $1. $2. etc); <hand-written script> }` loop (because it implicitly is!).

Comment: ` prevChar == "#" when awk moves to the next line.` so that means it has access to the value of prevChar from prev line

Comment: Yes, just like for any other programming language that's processing a text file inside a `while read { ... }` loop, awk variables don't just retain their value while reading the current line, they retain them for the rest of the process execution (or until they leave the current scope if local but all awk vars are global unless listed as function args). Awk is for the most part just like C or Pascal or any other Algol-based language except it has that implicit loop I mentioned in my previous comment and a basic `<condition> { <action> }` syntax within that loop.

Comment: I updated the question to show what the script would look like if you wrote it in a C-like syntax to hopefully help you understand the control flow.

Comment: can you also explain the c like syntax for my question about `awk '/Linux/{x=NR+2}(NR<=x){print}' file` What i undestand is `while read (file,line) {if {line ~ '/Linux/'} then { x = NR + 2; print}}`  I dont understand how (NR<=x) work

Comment: Any questions about a different question you should post in that question so others reading that question can benefit from any answer you get.

Answer (score 2):

If awk is also an option, here is a portable one:

```
awk 'match($0,/^ *\* */){
  if(b) $0=b substr($0,RLENGTH+1)
  else b=substr($0,1,RLENGTH)
} /^#/{b=""} 1' file
```

**Explanation**:

- `b` stands for *beginning* in the sense you used it in your question (n space * n space),
- `match($0, /^ *\* */)` is almost the same as `/^ *\* */`, it matches zero or more spaces followed by an `*` followed by zero or more spaces at the beginning of `$0` (i.e current line). If there is a match, `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are set to the position where matched substring starts and its length respectively,

  - `if (b)` is a shorthand for `if (b != "")` and safe to use here bacause `b`'s value can't be 0 in this case,
  - `$0 = b substr($0, RLENGTH + 1)` replaces the *beginning* of current line with `b`,
  - `b = substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)` sets `b` to the *beginning* of current line,
- `/^#/ { b = "" }` means if current line begins with an `#` reset `b`,
- `1` means print `$0`.

Comment: I will try this

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it:

```
sed '/^#/{N;p;s/.*\n//;s/[^ *].*//;h;d;};s/^[ *]*//;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/'
```

Translated:
If the line starts with '#', read the following line as well, print them both, then remove the first line and everything after the string of spaces and stars, then put what's left (i.e. the string of spaces and stars) in the hold space, and end.
Otherwise, remove the leading spaces and stars, append the contents of the hold space (i.e. the desired string of spaces and stars), then swap the two parts (thereby bringing the desired prefix to the front).

Comment: can you explain the syntax

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: No, for that you need a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file try gnu sed,

```
sed -E ':b /#/{n; p;s/(\s*\*\s*).+/\1/;h;Tb;:l $!N;s/(.*)\n[* ]+(.+)/\1\2/;Tn;p;g;bl;:n D}' d
```

Comment: can you explain the syntax

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi this and the other sed answer are what I'm talking about when I said elsewhere about only using sed for s/old/new/ - if you try to do anything else you end up with just a pile of incomprehensible runes. It looks very clever and impressive but is this REALLY what you want to come across in your software when you go to enhance or debug it 6 months later?